# Get Database schema and generate script - programatically vb.net

Tags: sql, xml, vb.net, database-schema

I am trying to write a vb.net program that connects to a server and gets the entire schema/metadata of a database and then generates it into a script that can be used to update the schema of the database in a different development environment. All this must me done through Visual studio (.net).

I have been searching high and low for a solution, but I have not come across anything that solves my problem.

The closest I have gotten was using the following code in a vb file and using VBC through the command prompt to generate a .exe that creates an xml file. The .vb file is contingent on a SQL query which is below. This SQL query only retrieves the tables, columns, and datatype of each column, I am trying to get the schema of the entire instance of the database

```
SELECT t.name AS TableName, SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id) AS SchemaName, c.name AS ColumnName, tp.name as DataType 
FROM sys.tables AS t 
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID 
INNER JOIN sys.types tp ON c.system_type_id =  tp.system_type_id ORDER BY TableName
```

I am not sure what else to do or where to look to find new things. Everything I have read is either only retrieving a Table schema with the GetSchema vb class among others OR it is generating the database schema script through SQL server management studio.

Any help and constructive input would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used the following resources to write the code

** connect to server and database and get schema and write in console

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms205738.aspx

** write to text file

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ka1wd3w.aspx

I ended up saving the file as an .sql

the actual code that gets the schema is as follows and can be found under the first link

```
For Each tb In db.Tables
    smoObjects = New Urn(0) {}
    smoObjects(0) = tb.Urn
    If tb.IsSystemObject = False Then
        Dim sc As StringCollection
        sc = scrp.Script(smoObjects)
        Dim st As String
        For Each st In sc
            Console.WriteLine(st)
        Next
    End If
Next
```

with the following imports

```
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Collections.Specialized
Imports System.Text
Imports System.IO
```